# Configuring Entitlement.plist for Xamarin.iOS with Azure AD B2C

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a **Xamarin.Forms** mobile app that uses **Azure AD B2C** for authentication.

On iOS devices when the user first launches the app, they are presented with the **Azure AD B2C** login form. They enter their credentials but are redirected back to the login page with the email address / password fields empty (incorrect). After a few seconds they are eventually logged in. When they subsequently launch the app, they have to re-enter their credentials again (also incorrect).

So the two problems with iOS are:

- Being redirected back to the login screen when they attempt to login to the app (but are then eventually logged in)
- The user has to keep entering their credentials every time they launch the app (after a successful login they should be automatically logged in)

After some investigation this seems to be because the token cache is not working with the method *AcquireTokenSilentAsync*() correctly. This seems to be related to the configuration of **Entitlements.plist**. I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) (right at the very bottom of the page) but still no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>AppPrefixIdentifier.OurAppBundleIdentifier</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any suggestions on how to configure **Entitlements.plist** to work with **Azure AD B2C**? Do we need to make any changes to the provisioning profile to use **Azure AD B2C**?

Comment: Is this help?[ios-app-is-not-returning-after-azure-ad-b2c-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563866/xamarin-ios-app-is-not-returning-after-azure-ad-b2c-login). And can you provide some codes to reproduce the problem? I test [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) here and it did go back to app after login successfully.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT That's the same Github project I used as the basis for our authentication code. The Android version works fine but not iOS. It does log you in, but the behaviour is incorrect (see my description above).

Comment: Yes, I tried the sample and can't reproduce the description you said above.  I suggest you open a free support case. That way you can provide a complete project that shows the issue securely and privately. You can open a free Xamarin support case here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=classiccommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16068&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636645150473349054)